# Attempting to extract stock prices using python

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I am currently trying to extract stock prices from a list of stock codes contained on a csv file by using pandas and yfinance.

I have 145 companies I need to do this for, is there a way of doing it? As I have tried over a period of 5 days without success.

I just need to know if its possible and what would you recommend to achieve this.

Comment: [Get Stock Price Data using Python](https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2021/12/21/get-stock-price-data-using-python/)

Answer (score 0):

`yfinance.Ticker(ticker).history(start=start_date)` gets you the data that you desire.

if you have a giant  *csv*, with a field `"ticker"`, you can create a *pandas dataframe* with the below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance
def read_create_giant_df(file_in):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_in)
    out = []
    for item in df["ticker"]:
        ticker_df = yfinance.Ticker(item).history(start="1930-01-01")
        ticker_df["ticker"] = item
        out.append(ticker_df)
    return pd.concat(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

below code should work , if any module missing use command to install it .

```
pip install yfinance 
pip install yahoofinancials
```

Run below code to get the data for Amazon-AMZN

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
amzn_df = yf.download('AMZN', 
                  start='2019-01-01', 
                  end='2019-12-31', 
                  progress=False)
amzn_df.head()
```

Comment: Ok thank you everyone   I will try both of these and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Python code that tries to import daily data for the ticker from `Yahoo Finance` first, and if that fails, then from `Alpha Vantage`. You can save this code as a separate module and then use its `import_ticker` function. I tried to make the code extensible so that additional data providers could be easily added.

Note. To use `Alpha Vantage`, you have to register and obtain a free API key.

```
from typing import Optional, Tuple

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pytest
import requests
import yfinance as yf

ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY = "YOUR_ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY_HERE"


def import_ticker_alpha_vantage(ticker: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    url = f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol={ticker}&apikey={ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY}&outputsize=full"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["Time Series (Daily)"]).transpose().sort_index()
    data = data.rename(
        columns={
            "1. open": "Open",
            "2. high": "High",
            "3. low": "Low",
            "4. close": "Close",
            "5. volume": "Volume",
        }
    )
    return data


def import_ticker_yahoo(ticker: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    data = yf.Ticker(ticker).history(period="max")
    data.index = data.index.date
    del data["Dividends"]
    del data["Stock Splits"]
    del data["Capital Gains"]
    return data


def _check_imported_data(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[bool, str]:
    if not isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        return False, "not pd.DataFrame"
    if df.empty:
        return False, "empty pd.DataFrame"
    if not set(df.columns.values) == {"Volume", "Close", "High", "Low", "Open"}:
        return False, f"wrong pd.DataFrame columns: {set(df.columns.values)}"
    all_columns_numeric = df.apply(
        lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors="coerce").notnull().all()
    ).all()
    if not all_columns_numeric:
        return False, "not all pd.DataFrame columns numeric"
    return True, "OK"


def import_ticker(ticker: str) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
    print(f"Trying to import data for {ticker} ticker from Yahoo Finance...")
    res = import_ticker_yahoo(ticker)
    if _check_imported_data(res) == (True, "OK"):
        print(f"Imported data for {ticker} ticker from Yahoo Finance - OK")
        return res
    print(f"Trying to import data for {ticker} ticker from Alpha Vantage...")
    res = import_ticker_alpha_vantage(ticker)
    if _check_imported_data(res) == (True, "OK"):
        print(f"Imported data for {ticker} ticker from Alpha Vantage - OK")
        return res
    print(f"Import data for {ticker} ticker FAILED")
    return None


###########################################################################

# I know having tests in the same file with code is a bad practices, please don't bother informing me.
# Run tests: pytest -o "python_files='*.py'" -s


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def imported_data_for_tests():
    """
    It should run import only once and use the result for all tests
    """
    print("Running import_ticker_yahoo in fixture...")
    res = import_ticker_yahoo("SPY")
    yield res


def test_check_imported_data_ok(imported_data_for_tests):
    assert _check_imported_data(imported_data_for_tests) == (True, "OK")


def test_check_imported_data_wrong_column_name(imported_data_for_tests):
    res = imported_data_for_tests.copy()
    res_column_renamed = res.rename(columns={"Volume": "Volume Renamed"})
    assert _check_imported_data(res_column_renamed) == (
        False,
        f"wrong pd.DataFrame columns: {set(res_column_renamed.columns.values)}",
    )


def test_check_imported_data_empty_df():
    assert _check_imported_data(pd.DataFrame()) == (False, "empty pd.DataFrame")


def test_check_imported_data_not_all_numeric_values(imported_data_for_tests):
    res_with_empty_val_in_column = imported_data_for_tests.copy()
    res_with_empty_val_in_column.iloc[
        -1, res_with_empty_val_in_column.columns.get_loc("Volume")
    ] = np.nan
    assert _check_imported_data(res_with_empty_val_in_column) == (
        False,
        "not all pd.DataFrame columns numeric",
    )


############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = import_ticker("CPER")
    print(res)
    if res:
        print(res.info())
```